# Would Mos be interested in a feed from Literature.SE?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-feed

In our main chatroom, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198), there are several feeds, all named Obie. There's regular Obie (main site questions), Meta Obie (meta questions), Blog Obie (new blog posts), and Movies & TV Obie (select tags from movies.SE).

So. Would Mos be interested in a feed from Literature.SE for certain select tags, such as [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [1984](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1984), [narnia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narnia), etc, named <s>Professor Obie</s> Lit Obie?

Comment: Are there any Mos users that would be interested that aren't already active in Lit? If the idea is to draw more users to Lit, like community ads, I guess I can see the appeal. Something to keep in mind for regulars is that you can ignore individual Obies.

Comment: Three downvotes? :-o

Comment: @Randal'Thor - yes. Most annoying :/...

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think it's an especially good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have mixed feelings about this. On one hand, Movies Obie works just fine and doesn't flood Mos with messages. On other hand, Literature currently doesn't have a [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) tag - in order to collect all *related* questions, we would have to build and constantly update a list of *individual works*, which will most certainly be a tedious task.

---

**But I propose we try this out.**

It could be interesting to see the works we know from the perspective of a community that is not science-fiction or fantasy oriented.

Here are the tags I propose:

[strugatsky-brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strugatsky-brothers) [j-r-r-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) [j-k-rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-k-rowling) [c-s-lewis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-s-lewis) [robert-jordan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-jordan) [rick-riordain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rick-riordain) [nineteen-eighty-four](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nineteen-eighty-four) [neil-gaiman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neil-gaiman) [patrick-rothfuss](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patrick-rothfuss)

Some of the authors listed have written works that are not science fiction or fantasy (hence no [george-orwell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-orwell)), but others are *mostly* science-fiction or fantasy writers; I guess we can tolerate some non-sci-fi question in our feed once in a while

Comment: The quality of the Movies Obie feed is questionable as well. It misses a lot of sci-fi questions because they're poorly tagged.

Comment: @Valorum the policy on Lit says all questions about a certain work get the author tag, so we're good here.

Comment: I'd be happier if we had a curated feed rather than an automated one.

Comment: @Valorum _sounds like an answer_

Comment: @Valorum - if you add an answer, we'll see what happens.... Although I don't know how to set up a curated feed.

Comment: @Mithrandir - I'm hesitant to put up an answer that says that someone else has to do work that I'm unwilling (and in this case, unable, since I'm not a room owner) to do myself. I'd rather they just post a feed, then bitch about it :-)

Comment: @Valorum Mith's feeling masochistic, who are we to deny him the pleasure? _Go for it_

Comment: @Valorum What do you mean by "curated"? Someone posting interesting questions manually? Or a feed as suggested in this answer but with the tags list being constantly updated by hand?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The former, at least for the time being.